# It is possible to select a ListView item with a single tap or left click?

Tags: windows-8, microsoft-metro, semantic-zoom

I am developing a Windows 8 metro application that uses semantic zoom in the following way:

- The zoomed in view contains a `ListView` with complex controls that allow for user interaction (by using TextBox and Button controls), therefore this ListView has `IsItemClickEnabled="False"`. The user must trigger the zoomed out view manually.
- The zoomed out view contains another `ListView` which displays a simple list that displays some status information for the controls in the zoomed in view. The `ItemsSource` property of this ListView is populated dinamically with plain objects that are created in the moment that the view is made active. This ListView has `IsItemClickEnabled="True"`.

**What do I want:**

When the user taps or clicks on an item in the zoomed out view, the zoomed in view should activate and the control matching the clicked item should be made visible (the zoomed in ListView allows scrolling, so the control could be hidden). I know how to do this as long as the `SelectionChanged` event is triggered when a item is clicked.

**What happens instead:**

When the user taps or clicks on an item in the zoomed out view, the zoomed in view activates automatically and no `SelectionChanged` event is triggered. However, it works fine when using right click or Ctrl+click instead.

**So, my question is:**

Is there any way to make a ListView trigger the `SelectionChanged` event on item tap or left click, in addition to right click and Ctrl+click? If not, how can I detect the tap or left click?

Thank you very much!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I found out the solution. I must control the `Tapped` event of the control that is inside the defined `DataTemplate` for the list, NOT the event of the `ListView` itself:

```
<SemanticZoom...>
    <SemanticZoom.ZoomedOutView>
        <ListView ...>
            <ListView.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <Border ... Tapped="Item_Tapped">
```

And in the `Item_Tapped` method, I just cast `sender` to `FrameworkElement` and look at its `DataContext`.

Answer (score 1):

There is no more click events in Windows 8 but instead there is gestures (i.e. Tapped, RightTapped, Holding) and pointers (i.e. Pressed, Released, Moved).
Starting from this you can handle through a switch different cases depending on the input devices which is used (i.e. Mouse, Pen, Touch).

Here a little piece of code as example.

```
void MyElement_Holding(object sender, Windows.UI.Input.HoldingEventArgs e)
{
    switch (e.PointerDeviceType)
    {
        case PointerDeviceType.Mouse:
            break;
        case PointerDeviceType.Pen:
            break;
        case PointerDeviceType.Touch:
            break;
    }
}
```

Hope this help.